# Redux-saga fetching data return undefined at first time then return data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I just learn react, and react native things, i watched a tutorial about redux-saga on internet and in that tutorial, he fetch data from json file using redux-saga, **but** data first return `undefined` then return that data, detail here, in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1K26DIKt3w8&t=1797s  (Timeline of above problem is **30:18**)

But i wonder how can we return these data without a `undefined` first time like the video. Here is his code on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-stoic-euler-cjhgx-forked-td1il

Here is some saga-part of his code

**Function HandleGetUser**

```
export function* handleGetUser(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGetUser);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setUser(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**Watch saga**

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_USER, handleGetUser);
}
```

**Action and reducer**

```
export const GET_USER = "GET_USER";
const SET_USER = "SET_USER";

export const getUser = () => ({
  type: GET_USER
});

export const setUser = (user) => ({
  type: SET_USER,
  user
});

const initialState = {
  user: undefined
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER:
      const { user } = action;
      return { ...state, user };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Thank you so much for help, that help beginer like us very much

Answer (score 1):

It is very normal that Redux api data is undefined first - after all, the component already renders even before you have requested data from the server and even then it will take some time to get a response - and React does not wait for that. You'd need to show a spinner or something.

Apart from that, I would highly encourage you not to follow that tutorial any more and stick to more official resources, as that tutorial is just outdated by years.

Generally, the [Redux Styleguide recommends to use thunks by default, not sagas](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-thunks-for-async-logic) as sagas add a lot of complexity and are most of the time just not necessary.

You are also writing a style of Redux that we are not really teaching any more and that is multiple times longer than necessary. The best way of learning Redux is to follow [the official essentials tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

For data fetching, the official Redux Toolkit even contains [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview), an abstraction that takes all the jobs of writing reducers etc. for data fetching.

Answer (score 0):

some times work like this try to remove call

```js
const response = yield requestGetUser();
```